# Adding composer to update core

Tags: composer, upgrading

I'm using a site created on Pantheon and now I'm not using pantheon.

So the core is not installed with composer.
Now I want to upgrade core with composer but I don't understand how.

I've some modules installed with composer, so I try to add drupal/core :

```
compose require "drupal/core"
```

It's ok, but if I try to this, the aren't upgrades:

```
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
```

I've core 8.6.1 and I wanto to update to 8.6.2.

Thanks

Comment: `So the core is not installed with Composer. Now I want to upgrade core with Composer.` What about installing it with Composer again?

Comment: What do you mean? I try to add drupal/core but, after this, it does not find upgrades

Comment: What do you mean with `it does not find upgrades`?

Comment: That is if i run "composer update "drupal/core" it tells me that there is nothing to install or upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably due to how the drupal/core line in your composer.json file is defined.  It probably has the version locked to 8.6.1.  So the update is saying: You are already at the version you requested.  There are no updates.

I would try doing the following:

```
composer require drupal/core:8.6.2 --update-with-dependencies
```

This will tell composer to use that version and ignore the version info in the composer.json file.

Comment: It doesn't work. If I run that command, composer returns me: Nothing to install or update

Comment: What does the entry for drupal/core in your composer.json line say? Also, do you have the drupal repository added in your composer.json file.  E.g.:
 "repositories": {
    "drupal": {
      "type" : "composer",
      "url" : "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },

Comment: yes, repo is there, because I've installed some modules with composer. Here is the compose.json: require": {  "drupal/core": "8.6.2" },
    "replace": {
        "drupal/core": "^8.6"
    },

Comment: Hmm, I would remove the replace statement since this is not a forked version and change the 8.6.2 version to 8.6.1.  Composer does not use Drupal version info just the composer version.  Since it says 8.6.2, I think it assumes you have 8.6.2 installed.  Then try the version specific require command.

Comment: Removing the replace statement I've upgrade the core. Thanks a lot. Some guide suggests to upgrade also symfony: have I to do this?

Comment: If you used one of the with-dependencies options, this should have updated the symfony and other components.  You can check this with the composer show command.  I think it should be V3.4.17 for most symfony.things.

Comment: I've 3.4.14. Is it wrong? If I remove vendor and then run "composer install", it remains on 3.4.14